# mongoDB how to get JSON of _id within single request

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm learning mongoDB and ran into a problem.

I have two collections:
posts and "controle"

in my posts collection

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"6332e9595140f74b61c43e5c"},
"title":"SF",
"img":"https://media.sss.com/1.png",
"desription":"This is the second post"}
```

and in "Controle"

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6332e99e5140f74b61c43e5d"},
"title":"Strict",
"posts":[{"$oid":"6332e9595140f74b61c43e5c"},{"$oid":"633020b131ca81e116d75a3f"}],
"type":"horizontal"}
```

how can I get data from "controle" in one request so that the response contains the title, img, description of each post from the array, not just ID's of objects.

Comment: [`"$lookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will do the job here.  Some of the examples in the link are close to what you want.

Comment: thank you!!! it's worked for me! who will face same problem just need after you receive response make it .toArray() if you use nodeJS

Comment: You can use the ```populate()``` method in mongoose(if you are using mongoose which is highly recommended), which will do your job. 
What happens here is, this will populate the response with all the attributes which is present and not just the _id
So basically your response contains all the data along with the _id

Comment: thank you, appreciate your answer, will try populate()